# Swagger, after code gen into html additionalProperties are not shown

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-codegen

Since keys of the object that my response returns are dynamic, i used `additionalProperties` to make them as such. While on the ui of the editor it shows properly, when i use code gen into html the response is missing fields. This is just one example, there are also similar components which are not rendered properly.

```
// my path
/cmc/assets:
  get:
    summary: Details of each currency available
      operationId: Get market assets
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content: 
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/MarketAsset'
        '400':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/400'
        '404':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/404'
        '500': 
          $ref: '#/components/responses/500' 

// component that the 200 response refers to
     MarketAsset:
      type: object
      additionalProperties: 
        type: object
        properties:
          name: 
            type: string
            example: "Purpose"
          unified_cryptoasset_id: 
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/PositiveStringInteger'
          can_withdraw:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/StringTrueOrFalse'
          can_deposit: 
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/StringTrueOrFalse'
          min_withdraw:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/PositiveStringFloatOrInt'
          max_withdraw:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/PositiveStringFloatOrInt'
          maker_fee: 
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/PositiveStringFloatOrInt'
          taker_fee:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/PositiveStringFloatOrInt'
      example: 
        name: "Purpose"
        unified_cryptoasset_id: "101"
        can_withdraw: "true"
        can_deposit: "false"
        min_withdraw: "100"
        max_withdraw: "1000"
        maker_fee: "0"
        taker_fee: "0"
```

In the editor:

[image]

The html ui:

[image]

I have tried both with and without examples but the result is the same, the editor ui works fine while generated html doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Open an issue at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues